# Variable hp not updating in 20x20 grid

Tags: java

I am currently working on a 20x20 2d-Array, where the user can input WASD to control their movements around the grid. I want to make it so that certain elements in their grid can affect their hp, however, the hp is not updating on my grid. Please help me see what is wrong.

The following code will set fixed number of certain Characters to an array, and fill the rest with E. There will be a person standing in a random position which is represented with a blank space. The user will then have to input either W, A, S or D, to control the movement of the person. As the person moves along the grid, he will interact with the element he is standing in, and thus his hp will be updated and then the character he is standing on will be replaced with a blank space.

```
package quest;
import java.util.*;
public class Quest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        char[][] board = new char[20][20];
        int [] current = new int[2];
        int hp = 100;
        int food = 0;
        int weapon = 0;
        int health = 0;
        int threats = 0;

        int turns = (int)(Math.random() * 76) + 25;
        int turnsCount = turns;
        System.out.println(turns);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'F';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'W';    
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'M';    
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'G'; 
        }    
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'S'; 
        }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'K';
        }    
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'C'; 
        }    
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)   
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = 'P'; 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)   
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            while (board[x][y] != '\u0000')
            {
                x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
                y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            }
            board[x][y] = ' ';
            current[0] = x;
            current[1] = y;
        }    
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
            {   
                board[x][y] = intializeGameBoard(board[x][y]);
                System.out.print(board[x][y]+"  ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < turns; j++)
        {
            char move =sc.next().charAt(0);
            int finalMove[] = makeAMove(move);   
            current[0] = current[0]+finalMove[1];
            current[1] = current[1]+finalMove[0];
            int newhp = updateHealth(board[0][1], hp);
            board[current[0]][current[1]] = ' ';
            turnsCount = turnsCount - 1; 

            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
                {   
                    board[x][y] = intializeGameBoard(board[x][y]);
                    System.out.print(board[x][y]+"  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("Turns left: " + turnsCount);
            System.out.println("Health: " + newhp);
        }    

    }
    public static char intializeGameBoard(char element)
    {
        if (element == '\u0000')
        {
            element = 'E';
        }
        return element;
    }
    public static int[] makeAMove(char move)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        if (move == 'w')
        {
            y = y - 1;
        }
        if (move == 'a')
        {
            x = x - 1;
        }    
        if (move == 's')
        {
            y = y + 1;
        }
        if (move == 'd')
        {   
            x = x + 1;
        }
        int [] finalMove = new int [2];
        finalMove[0] = x;
        finalMove[1] = y;
    return finalMove;
    }
    public static int updateHealth(char element, int hp)
    {
        int newhp;
        if (element == 'F')
        {
            newhp = hp+5;
        }
        if (element == 'M')
        {
            newhp = hp+10;
        }
        if (element == 'G')
        {
            newhp = 0;
        }
        if (element == 'S')
        {
            newhp = hp-3;
        }
        if (element == 'K')
        {
            newhp = hp-5;
        }
        if (element == 'C')
        {
            newhp = hp-5;
        }
        else
        {
            newhp = hp;
        }    
    return newhp;    

    }        
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code here. Have you tried to use a debugger to identify a problem? Perhaps you could show a [mcve]?

Comment: Please give an example of a sequence of user input and the desired behavior you want to see. Also, how does this differ from what actually happens when you run your code?

Comment: I suggest you learn about Object Oriented Programming. In particular, you need to learn about the difference between static and non-static methods and variables as well as about how to create instances of objects from a class.

Comment: You also need to learn about variable scope and the difference between local variables and member fields.

Comment: Did you happen to learn about `Map`? It will greatly help you reduce and maintain the code.

Comment: You get newhp back from your updatehealth method and then don't use it. Simply assign the value to hp instead of newhp. Or copy newhp into hp when you're ready to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems that the other answers brought up, but neither got it exactly right nor explained why you get your behavior.

- Look at this snippet:

  ```
  if (element == 'S')
  {
      newhp = hp-3;
  }
  if (element == 'K')
  {
      newhp = hp-5;
  }
  if (element == 'C')
  {
      newhp = hp-5;
  }
  else
  {
      newhp = hp;
  }
  ```

  The last `else` is the alternative only to the last `if`. So, if your letter is `S` it will do the following:

  1. Check if the letter is `S`. Yes: `newhp = hp - 3`.
  2. Check if the letter is `K`. No: do nothing.
  3. Check if the letter is `C`. No: skip to its `else`.
  4. `else`: newhp = hp.

  So you reset what you did previously. Put an `else` before all but the first `if` in the method. This way it is guaranteed that only 1 action will be taken.
- You pass the wrong arguments to `updateHealth`:

  ```
  updateHealth(board[0][1], hp);
  ```

  This will always pass the letter at `(0, 1)`. Instead, you want to pass the current location as

  ```
  updateHealth(board[current[0]][current[1]], hp);
  ```
- You return the new hp value, but you don't update the old one:

  ```
  int newhp = updateHealth(..., hp);
  ```

  And the next time you call this, you pass the same `hp` you passed last time. You don't need the `newhp` variable at all, just use `hp`.

**Extra:**

- Your `makeAMove` method is written oddly:

  ```
  int y = 0;
  if (move == 'w') {
      y = y - 1;
  }
  ```

  is the same as

  ```
  int y = 0;
  if (move == 'w') {
      y--; // or y = -1;
  }
  ```

  And you are checking possibilities that can't be reached because you forgot `else`s there too. Try something like this:

  ```
  public static int[] makeAMove(char move) {

      int[] finalMove = new int[2];
      if (move == 'w') {
          finalMove[1] = -1;
      }
      else if (move == 'a') {
          finalMove[0] = -1;
      }
      else if (move == 's') {
          finalMove[1] = 1;
      }
      else if (move == 'd') {
          finalMove[0] = 1;
      }
      return finalMove;
  }
  ```
- Do a check when you move outside the edge of the board and disallow that. Otherwise you "crash" the game.
- Using `switch` statements will help your code, and `Map`s even more so.
- You don't need to call `intializeGameBoard` after every move. In fact, if the default letter is `E`, just loop through the array in the beginning and put that one everywhere. When iterating over an array, use its `length` property as the loop condition instead of a number, because when it changes in one place you will forget to change it somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have totally forgotten about the else resetting my whole if statements. I have taken into account with what you had wrote in and it works perfectly now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `int newhp = updateHealth(board[0][1], hp)` to `int newhp = updateHealth(board[current[0]][current[1]], hp);`

You are passing the same character each time. you should also set `hp = newhp;` after printing the hp.

Also change your updateHealth method to use if/else.

Comment: Did you try this? Don't guess - post what you know is a correct answer.

Comment: Yes I did actually try this, thanks. I didn't refactor as much code as you did but this will work.

Comment: Well, after you added the *"Also change your updateHealth method to use if/else."* it will work, but your original answer wouldn't have :)

Comment: The answer was correct when you asked, was it not ;)?

Comment: No. Look at the timestamps when you posted, when I commented, and when you edited. I'm just suggesting you to really test the answer *before posting* to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're using a load of if statements. You need to use only ONE if statement in parallel (Same indentation), and the rest should be else if. It'd also be a bit cleaner to do a switch(element)/case. Displayed below in both forms:

```
public static int updateHealth(char element, int hp)
    {
        int newhp;
        if (element == 'F')
        {
            newhp = hp+5;
        }
        else if (element == 'M')
        {
            newhp = hp+10;
        }
        else if (element == 'G')
        {
            newhp = 0;
        }
        else if (element == 'S')
        {
            newhp = hp-3;
        }
        else if (element == 'K')
        {
            newhp = hp-5;
        }
        else if (element == 'C')
        {
            newhp = hp-5;
        }
        else
        {
            newhp = hp;
        }    
    return newhp;    
    }
```

Using switch(element)/case:

```
public static int updateHealth(char element, int hp)
    {
        int newhp;
        switch(element){
            case(F):
                newhp=hp+5
                break;
            case(M):
                newhp=hp+10
                break;
            case(G):
                newhp=0
                break;
            case(S):
                newhp=hp-3
                break;
            case(K):
                newhp=hp-5
                break;
            case(C):
                newhp=hp-5
                break;
            default:
                newhp = hp;
        }   
    return newhp; 
    }
```

Comment: I have tried converting to switch statements, however, my health still display as 100 despite landing on the elements that should change the health.

Comment: In that case, try putting in the first change I gave (Else if), and if that doesn't work, I recommend stepping through with a debugger from line 130 (in the code segment you gave). Good luck!

Comment: If you don't know what the answer is, it's better to try it yourself to make sure it works or not post guesses at all. You can give advice in comments.